# GC not able to collect back memory using fork-emulation on Windows

Tags: multithreading, perl, garbage-collection

Let me begin by saying I do not have in depth knowledge of Perl so please pardon me if there is something obvious that I have missed :)

In the system (running in Windows environment) that I am looking at, we have a perl process which has to download ~5000-6000 files. Since each file can be independently downloaded, we forked separate threads for each file. The thread is supposed to download the file and die. On running the process, I noticed that the memory of the process goes up to ~1.7 GB and then dies due to the memory limit of each process.

On searching and asking a few people, I came across this concept of circular referencing due to which the garbage collector will not free up memory. I searched a bit and found the `Devel-Cycle` package which can find out if there are any cycles in the object. I got this package and added a line to check if the main object in the process has any cycles. `find_cycle` came back with the following statement for each thread.

```
DBD::Oracle::db FIRSTKEY failed: handle 2 is owned by thread 256004 not current thread c0ea29c (handles can't be shared between threads and your driver may need a CLONE method added) at C:/Program Files/Perl/site/lib/Devel/Cycle.pm line 151.
```

I got to know that DB handles cannot be shared between threads. I looked at the code again and realised that after the fork happens, the child process does actually create a new DB handle (which I guess is why the process still continues to run fine till it reaches the memory limit). I guess there might be more db handles from the parent in the object that are not used by the child but are still referenced.

Questons that I have -

1. Is the circular reference the only reason for the problem or could there be other issues causing the process to use so much memory?
2. Could the sharing of the handle cause the blow up in memory (in other words is the shared DB handle causing the GC to not free up space)?
3. If it is indeed the shared DB handle, I guess I can just say `$dbHandle = 0` to get rid of the reference (if `$dbHabndle` is referencing that particular handle). Am I correct here?
4. I am trying to go through the code to see where else there is a reference to the parent DB handle (and found at least one more reference). Is there any other way I can do this? Is there a method to print out all the properties of an object?

**EDIT:** 
Not all threads (due to the perl fork call in windows) are spawned at the same time. It spawns a max of n number of threads (where n is a configurable number). Once a thread has finished its execution, the process spawns another thread. At this moment n is set to 10, however I had changed n to 1 (so only one extra thread is running at one time), and I still hit the memory limit.

Comment: What does your code look like? What modules do you use? How do you use them? Need more details.

Comment: @TLP - I have only mentioned the main part of the process which I think is causing the problem. It is part of a much larger system which uses loads of modules like DBD::Oracle, XML::Simple, Net::FTP, File::Path etc.

Comment: Do you disconnect your database handles after using them?

Comment: Circular references are one of the major ways of creating a memory leak in Perl - it uses reference counting to detect if memory may be released. A circular reference will never drop to zero, therefore it won't ever release.

Comment: @TLP - looking at the code, I do not think that is happening right now. Let me check that again and fix that if it indeed is the case. However, will that cause the memory to blow up? Shouldn't the reference of the handle object be out of scope once the thread has finished and hence garbage collected.

Comment: @Harsha It's just a wild guess. Of the modules you listed, the database module sounded like the most likely suspect. For me it is impossible to know for sure without seeing some more detail.

Answer (score 5):

**edit**: Turns out, this does not solve the Ops problem. Still might be helpful for a future reader.

We do not really know a lot about your situation and your program sounds quite complex to just fork it 6000 times to me. But i will still attempt to answer, please correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

It appears you are on Windows. It is important to note, that Windows has no `fork()` system call. And as you specifically note that you "fork", i just assume that you actually use that Perl command. On windows, this will try to emulate `fork()` as best as it can but what that basically means is, that all the forked processes you see, are in fact just threads within the original process, just pretending to be processes to you. To do this, they copy the complete interpreter state. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html for more information. Especially the following part seems to apply to you:

> Resource limits
>
> In the eyes of the operating system, pseudo-processes created via the fork() emulation are simply threads in the same process. This means that any process-level limits imposed by the operating system apply to all pseudo-processes taken together. This includes any limits imposed by the operating system on the number of open file, directory and socket handles, limits on disk space usage, limits on memory size, limits on CPU utilization etc.

If you fork so many pseudo processes, you need a lot of memory as you also have to copy the interpreter state as often. And depending on the complexity of your program and how it is structured, that may very well be a non-trivial amount of memory.

And as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx tells us, the 1.7GB you mentioned, is not far away from the 2GB that some Windows versions impose on you as memory limit for a single process.

My wild guess would be, that you in fact just hit that limit by spawning all those many many threads, each with its own copy of the interpreter state and everything.

You will probably be off a lot better using some threading library instead of asking Perl to emulate individual processes for you. Needless to mention (i hope) that you do not really gain any advantage by having 6000 threads over lets say 16. If you try to have all of them do something at the same time, you will in fact most likely experience slowdowns, depending on how the threading is handled.

Comment: "you do not really gain any advantage by having 6000 threads over lets say 16" Unless, of course, their machine has 6000 cores ;)

Comment: Apologies @DeVadder, I did not explain myself very well. Your explanation of fork is correct, and the process does spawn different threads. However it does not spawn 6000 threads at the same time. It ensures that there are a max of 10 threads at any point in time. Once a thread finishes its job and dies, it spawns 1 more thread.

Comment: Let me edit the question to reflect that part. Apologies for not explaining that in the first place

Comment: @Harsha Hmm, so if you actually `wait` for and reap your pseudo-processes one by one but still have a memory leak, that implies that the fork emulation fails at reclaiming all the memory from the pseudo-children. In that case, i cannot help you expect suggesting to use Linux (i know, probably not a viable option) where the existence of actual `fork()` would make it irrelevant whether the GC was able to clean everything in the children once they are reaped. Unless of course the leak is somehow in the original process. ^^

Comment: @DeVadder I just wrote a quick program which forks 10 threads (each taking some memory) and waits and reaps further threads to always keep it to 10 threads. The memory of the process does increase (and stays pretty much constant). So obviously the memory leak is somewhere buried in the code and original process :( I solved the problem of DB handles but that does not help as well. Guess I need to do a lot more investigation

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments already provided, I want to emphasize the point DeVadder made regarding the behavior of fork in Windows and that Perl threading is likely a better solution but are you sure that the DBD module is safe to be used by multiple processes / forks / threads, etc without setting some extra parameters?

I had a similar error when using the DBI module to access a SQLite DB in multi-processed code using the threads module. It was solved by setting the 'use_immediate_transaction' option for the database handle provided by DBI to 1. If you aren't familiar with how Perl threads work, they aren't threads, they create a copy of the interpreter and everything you have in memory at the time of their creation, but even if I made the database handle separately in each "thread" I would get 'database locked' and various other errors. Without some of these extra options DBD may not function correctly in a multiprocessed environment.

Also, why make 6000 forks, use thread::queue and the threads module, make a worker pool of a few workers (one per core?) and recycle the workers. You are doing alot of overhead every fork for no gain.

Comment: The system has been up and running for more than 2 years, so I guess for tillnow we did not have any major problems with the DBD module (of course I can't be sure that it will not create problems later). Maybe threads is a a better solution, but I am not sure why the original designer (who does not work with us now unfortunately) chose to go the fork way.